# Как выбрать информацию из Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть у меня форма на стороне клиента с двумя выпадющими меню, он там выбирает год и тип обложки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В контроллере я собираю эти данные.И из исходя из этого делаю запрос в таблицу.Логично, если ничего не выбрано, то я данные подгружаю все.

```
string sql_count = string.Format("SELECT count(*) FROM labirint");
string sql_pages = string.Format(" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT "+ skip +", 10");
string sql_all = string.Format("SELECT * FROM labirint");
string sql_result = string.Format(sql_all + sql_pages);

 var v = dc.Database.SqlQuery<labirint>(sql_result).AsQueryable();
 recordsTotal = dc.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql_count).First();
 var data = v.ToList();
 dc.Dispose();
 return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Вот так это выглядит, когда таблица загружается по умолчанию.Теперь когда выбирают год. Я делаю склейку строки.

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
        {
            int year_int = int.Parse(year);
            string sql_year = string.Format(" WHERE year = " + year_int + "");

            sql_result = string.Format(sql_all + sql_year + sql_pages);
            sql_count = string.Format(sql_count + sql_year);

        }
```

В итоге получается вот так

```
string sql_count = string.Format("SELECT count(*) FROM labirint");
string sql_pages = string.Format(" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT "+ skip +", 10");
string sql_all = string.Format("SELECT * FROM labirint");
string sql_result = string.Format(sql_all + sql_pages);


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
        {
            int year_int = int.Parse(year);
            string sql_year = string.Format(" WHERE year = " + year_int + "");

            sql_result = string.Format(sql_all + sql_year + sql_pages);
            sql_count = string.Format(sql_count + sql_year);

        }

 var v = dc.Database.SqlQuery<labirint>(sql_result).AsQueryable();
 recordsTotal = dc.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql_count).First();
 var data = v.ToList();
 dc.Dispose();
 return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Все прекрасно работает. Но скорее всего написал я это все криво и не красиво . Проблемы начинаются, когда я хочу отсортировать по обложке. Выбрал я к примеру год 2013 и хочу выбрать все книги с твердой обложкой или на оборот. Как мне это сделать?  Возможно будет и третье поле с дропбоксом.

Comment: Извините, но четко сформулированного вопроса у вас нет. Но есть лишь только визуально оформленный процесс внутренней самокритики и рефлексии.

Comment: @Bulson Выбрал я к примеру год 2013 и хочу выбрать все книги с твердой обложкой или на оборот. Как мне это сделать ума не прилажу.

Comment: @Bulson Вот и есть вопрос. причем тут самокритика?

Comment: Если хотите гибкости то лучше использовать Linq в связке с Entity Framework. А стоп, `dc` - это `DbContext` ?

Comment: @koks_rs спасибо за совет. Но с линком проблемы, он плохо работает с большой базой. Скорость очень низкая и я решил использовать прямые запросы, где прозрачно и понятно.

Comment: Зашивать параметры в sql запрос очень дурная практика, это с одной стороны ухудшает производительность, так как каждый такой запрос серверу придётся анализировать заново (параметризированные запросы sql сервер может взять из хэша), во вторых это даёт возможность sql инъекций. Т.е. вместо WHERE year = " + year_int + "" лучше сделать SqlQuery("select * from labirint WHERE year = @year",  new SqlParameter("@year", year_int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var where = new List<string>();
 var query_params = new List<SqlParameter>();
 var limit_sql = "LIMIT @skip, 10";
 query_params.Add(new SqlParameter("@skip", int.Parse(skip)));

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year))
 {
     where.Add("year = @year");
     query_params.Add(new SqlParameter("@year", int.Parse(year)));
 }

 if(условие)
 {
    where.Add(...);
    query_params.Add(...);
 }

var whereSql = where.Any() ? " WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", where) : "";
var sql_result = select_sql + where_sql + order_sql + limit_sql;
var data = dc.Database.SqlQuery<labirint>(sql_result, query_params.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

После `WHERE year = " + year_int + ""` должно быть `AND oblojka = 'tverdaya'`. Но лучше все же не писать SQL-запросы самому, используйте ORM или, если это слишком медленно для вас, хотя бы [DbExtensions](http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/) или что-то легковесное типа [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#performance-of-select-mapping-over-500-iterations---poco-serialization)

Comment: Dapper не генерирует запросы, он только Mapping делает.
Писать запросы стоит, особенно если нужна производительность, ORM не решает все задачи.

Comment: тогда хранимая процедура. Потому что, если формировать запросы по уму, скорее всего, все сведется к формированию SQL строки на основе expression trees. Взять вот пример в вопросе. В форме три поля фильтрации и уже, код, мягко говоря не очень. Можно налажать с конкатенацией строк, можно забыть экранирование значений, а если джойны пойдут - пиши пропало.